# C# Invalid expression term '+='

Tags: c#

```
for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    string point_value += dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value + "|"; 
}
```

Does anyone know why I am getting this error

> Invalid expression term '+='

for this code?

Comment: What do you intend for that code to do? Since you're declaring a new string on that line then `string point_value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value + "|";`  would work and do the same thing. If you're trying to add to a string that was declared outside the loop then `point_value += dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value + "|"; ` is probably what you want. Not your issue yet, but `<=` in the loop condition is incorrect, it should be `<`.

Comment: If you are tracking point value, take out the variable to outer scope as described in answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you create new variable with in your for loop that the reason

if you need to store data each loop you should create variable outside loop

like this

```
string point_value = "";
for(int i=0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        point_value += dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value + "|"; 
    }
```

for more information about loop pattern [here](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-for-loop)

(**edited** to avoid empty value and out of range from DiplomacyNotWar's commented)

Comment: Thanks about it bro, I make a mistake putting variable in the loop.

Comment: I don't think this will compile because `point_value` doesn't have a value assigned to it. And it will also cause an `IndexOutOfRangeException` when `i == dataGridView1.Rows.Count` because `<=` is used instead of `<` (though I aprpeciate this issue was present in OP's original code).

Comment: I declare it as point_value = "point:" and it can works.
I use i to only get the total rows from the DGV so after I try no problem with it.